# Differential signalling with negative feedback

Tags: signal, differential, output, negative-feedback

Does differential signalling always comes hand to hand with a negative feedback circuit?Else the 1s and 0s would be the same!because if we have ground in the inverting pin then the output voltage will be 0 regardless of the resistances.

Comment: Is there a diagram to describe the arrangment you mention?

Answer (score 1):

No, not necessarily. The receiver might just compare if input A voltage is above or below input B voltage. So the absolute voltages are not that important, the difference is.

If you have 0V at the receiver inverting pin, and the receiver has a threshold of say 200mV, then the non-inverting pin being below 200mV is 0 and above 200mV is 1.